# How to retrieve nested data from addSuccessListener firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm Firebase new here and I'm trying to retrieve the nested data from firebase. I have spent the whole day but can't deal with it.

this is my object structures

```
data class Punch(
  var roundID: Int = 0,
  var isCorrect: Boolean = true,
  var speed: Double = 0.0
)

data class Training(
  var sessionID: String = "",
  var userId: String = "",
  var username: String = "",
  var date: Date = Date(),
  var round_Sessions: MutableList<RoundInfor>
)

data class RoundInfor(
  var roundID: String = "",
  var round_length: Double = 0.0,
  var total_punches: Int = 0,
  var correct_punches: Int = 0,
  var incorrect_punches: Int = 0,
  var avg_heart_rate: Double = 0.0,
  var avg_speed: Double = 0.0,
  var punches: MutableList<Punch>
)
```

My data structure

[image]

For example: I'm trying to save data from round_Sessions and punches. How could I dig into this?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image. Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: None of the code you shared shows any interaction with the Firebase API, so it's hard to say what problems you may be having there. Can you edit your question to show a [minimal, complete repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please read the link, it's quite useful).